# How to add time based access permission for spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I have created a college test paper and will assessment input through google spreadsheet.
Sheet is already share in read only mode and link will be access at specified time interval inenter code here write mode.
I have write a function to achieve this like below.

For testing purpose I have created and execute for today, but it is not working, can you rovide me some guideline to correct my code why it is not running.

```
function getSheetName(index) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var allSheetN

ames = new Array();
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:35 PM"

//may'15, will access in write mode between 3:00 to 5:00 PM
  if (currentdate = "2014-05-09" & currentTime >= "3:00 PM" & currentTime <= "5:00 PM"){
    ss.addEditor(pro_sjhot@gmail.com);
  }
  else if (currentTime < "3:00 PM" & currentTime > "5:00 PM") // for rest of the day it will show in read only mode
  {
    ss.removeEditor(pro_sjhot@gmail.com);
    ss.addViewer(pro_sjhot@gmail.com);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not good in google apps scripting, but at first glance I am not sure if this works:

**if (currentdate = "2014-05-09" & currentTime >= "3:00 PM" & currentTime <= "5:00 PM")**

your variable currentdate is **Date()** whereas in the code you want it to behave as a **string** (I don't see any conversions in your code). Also make sure that your currentTime really returns values in **12h** format and not **24h** format.

Hope it helps

Finally: comming from C# area, don't you need double **&&** in your code? I mean if code should not look like this:

**if (currentdate = "2014-05-09" && currentTime >= "3:00 PM" && currentTime <= "5:00 PM")**

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would require you to actually run it at some point as the owner. You can use triggers to do this for you. There are triggers that you can setup that will run the desired function as specific times.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers

So, write a function that will change the desired permissions. Then setup a time base trigger to run this. Make sure to run the function at least once, so you make sure you the owner have the correct permission to run the function when it does trigger. If you don't, google will prompt you and allow you to authorize.